# Transformation of random variable-exponential

Tags: distributions, random-variable, exponential-distribution

Let $Y=[X-C]^+$ is non-negative, where $X$ is an exponentially distributed random variable with parameter $\lambda$, and $C$ is a positive constant. What is the distribution and CDF for $Y$?

Comment: What have you done towards finding the answer? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I know the procedure for finding PFD if X to Y in one-to-one function. But here X to Y is not one to one I am struggling where to start.

Comment: I started with an expression of pdf for the linear transformation of Random variable Y=aX+b, considering a=1 and b=-c. However, as in my case as X to Y is not one-to-one, I think there should be more accurate answer.

Comment: You might start by considering the CDF of X. Then think about how the transformation to Y shifts around the probability mass. (For this it might help to draw a picture.)

Comment: Hint: $Y$ is _not_ a continuous random variable and does not have a density function. Thus, the procedure that you know will not work anyway. Follow GeoMatt22's hint to determine the CDF of $Y$ in terms of the CDF of $X$.

Comment: You need self study tag.

Answer (score 1):

To finish this off, first let $X$ have an exponential distribution with density $f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x \ge 0, \lambda > 0$ and cumulative distribution function (CDF) $F_X(x)$. Let $C>0$ be a positive constant.

Define $Y=|X-C|^+$ be the positive part of $X-C$, where the positive (negative) part functions are defined by $f^+(x)=\max(f(x),0)$ ($f^-(x)=\max(-f(x),0)$) and you can check that $f(x) = f^+(x) - f^-(x)$.
The distribution of $Y$ will have an atom at zero and a continuous part above zero. Then you can find the distribution by conditioning. I will only give the beginning of the argument. Let $y \ge 0$.
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
   \P(Y \le y) = \P(|X-C|^+ \le y) \\
   = \P(|X-C|^+ \le y \mid X\le C)\cdot \P(X \le C) + \P(|X-C|^+ \le y \mid X > C) \cdot \P(X>C) \\
=\P(0\le y)\cdot\P(X\le C) + \P(X-C\le y)\cdot \P(X>C) \\
= \dots
$$
and then it should not be difficult to finish.

Comment: Effective post, kjetil (+1). I have removed two typos (check). One thing that I am confused is re the notation you used: $|X-C|^+;$ if you need the positive part, isn't $(X-C) ^+$ enough instead of using the $\vert \cdot\vert$ sign? I thought it was absolute sign but then you are using the positive part, so it feels redundant, imo :-)